# Problem creating custom GIcon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I used to have something like this -

```
var gicons = [];

var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9,34);
baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20,34);
baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9,2);

gicons["home"] = new GIcon(baseIcon,"yellow.png"); 
gicons["red"] = new GIcon(baseIcon,"red.png");
gicons["green"] = new GIcon(baseIcon,"green.png");
gicons["blue"] = new GIcon(baseIcon,"blue.png");`
```

It works fine.
Instead of that, I would like something like -

```
var tags = ["home", "red","green", "blue"];
var tags_colors = ["yellow.png", "red.png", "green.png", "blue.png"];

for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++){

   if(tags[i]!=null){ 
      gicons[tags[i]] = new GIcon(baseIcon,tags_colors[i]); 
   }
}
```

::::::EDIT::::

`   GDownloadUrl("genxml.php", function(doc) {
                var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
                var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

```
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              // obtain the attribues of each marker
                var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("area");
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("street");
                var html = "<b>"+name+"<\/b><p>"+address;
                var category = markers[i].getAttribute("tag");
                // create the marker
                var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                tags[i] = markers[i].getAttribute('tag');

            }

            // hadnling the tags dynamically, to make it unique

           for (var i=0; i<tags.length-1 ; i++){
                var temp = tags[i];
                for(var j=i+1; j<tags.length; j++){
                     if(temp == tags[j]){
                        tags[j] = null; 
                     }
                }`
```

It is not working. No idea why. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
var tag_colors =.....
    tags_colors[i]
```

However, i would prefer to use 1 object instead of 2 arrays:

```
var gicons={};
var tags = {'home'  :'yellow.png',
            'red'   :'red.png',
            'green' :'green.png',
            'blue'  :'blue.png'
           };

for(var k in tags){
  gicons[k] = new GIcon(baseIcon,tags[k]); 
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

See the callback-function for `GDownloadUrl("genxml.xml")`

You create the marker there in line 224 of the linked document, inside the callback

```
var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
```

But you create the GIcon later inside the callback-function(line 257)

```
gicons[temp_tag] = new GIcon(baseIcon,tags_colors[i]);
```

The result is: inside  `createMarker()` the gicons-object is still empty, `gicons[category]` is unknown when supplied as argument to `new GMarker()`

So the dynamic creation of the GIcons works fine(you can inspect it inside firebugs DOM-tab), but it comes to late.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. In my actual code there is no typo. Still not working :( I edited that.

Comment: There is no further error, can you please post the current code starting at `var gicons = [];`

Comment: Actually I'm getting the value of tag from an automatically generated XML file. So, it is dynamic. Here's the chunk of code -

Comment: Is this online somewhere? the error would be easier to find with a working example.